# How do you pronounce this possessive - Trask's?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Trask's** life

How do you pronounce Trask’s?

Comment: you add an /s/ after saying *Trask*.  The same as you would add an *s* after saying *Jim* in *Jim's*.

Comment: Speakers of [African American Vernacular English](http://linguistlist.org/topics/ebonics/) often enunciate **ask** as **ax**. If they were talking about something belonging to Trask, they'd probably just call it **Trax [whatever]**.

Comment: *Ax* is a historical feature of many dialects, US and British, and is  not, I think, generalized to other *-ask* words. The ordinary reduction of these in US speech is *-ass*, and I think that in rapid informal speech *Trask's* would come out /træs:/, with a [geminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination#English) /s/. But that is not a pronunciation which a learner need or should emulate; ordinary /sks/ will not sound overprecise or affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pronounce it in the same way in which you pronounce any noun ending in -sk in the plural: *disks, tasks, desks*; or any verb ending in -sk in the present simple third person singular: *asks*. There is no exception of a rule here, it follows the rule and you simply say an additional /s/ sound after the name.